# Extract substrings before or after underscore

Tags: php, regex, string, substring, preg-match-all

I tried to use the `preg_match_all()` function to search for a string after the `_`. The output that I want will be `reset,text,email`. I tried to make it using the [regexr](http://regexr.com/)  editor and able to make it with `[_]+[a-z]*` but this will include the `_reset, _text, _text`. The string will be:

```
$str = 'button_reset,location_text,email_text';
```

**Expected output:**

```
reset
text
email
```

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense. "email" is not after the underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be better to avoid regex for this task and just use `str_replace()`:

Input:

```
$str = 'button_reset,location_text,email_text';
```

Code for output as array:

```
var_export(explode(',',str_replace(['button_reset','location_text','email_text'],['reset','text','email'],$str)));
// array (
//    0 => 'reset',
//    1 => 'text',
//    2 => 'email',
// )
```

---

Or if you insist, Regex ([Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/Rp4lOe/1)):

```
/button_\K[^,]+|,location_\K[^,]+|,\K[^_]+(?=_text)/
```

Regex Breakdown:

```
button_\K[^,]+     #Match one or more non-comma-characters after button_
|                  #or
,location_\K[^,]+  #Match one or more non-comma-characters after location_
|                  #or
,\K[^_]+(?=_text)  #Match one or more non-underscore-characters that are
                   # immediately followed by _textafter button_
```

The `\K` in each conditional expression means match from this point and effectively removes the need to use capture groups for this case.
When using capture groups, `preg_match_all()` creates multiple subarrays -- one filled with fullstring matches, and at least one more with captured values.
`\K` should be used whenever possible because it cuts array size by up to 50%.

Code:

```
$array=preg_match_all('/button_\K[^,]+|,location_\K[^,]+|,\K[^_]+(?=_text)/',$str,$out)?$out[0]:[];
var_export($array);
```

Same output:

```
array ( 0 => 'reset', 1 => 'text', 2 => 'email', )
```

Comment: I want to use the preg_match()

Comment: It is not the wise choice this time.  I can make one but it's not the right function for this task.  Give me a minute.

Answer (score 3):

**Regex:** `/\_\K[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

> **1.** `\_\K` This will match `_` and `\K` will reset the whole match.
>
> **2.** `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` will match all these characters

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/787457)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$str = 'button_reset,location_text,email_text';
preg_match_all("/\_\K[a-zA-Z0-9]+/",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => reset
            [1] => text
            [2] => text
        )
)
```